# Comparing big numbers

Tags: c++

I have to compare big numbers, these numbers are 1 < 2 numbers < 10^1000. Operators are: ==,!=,>,<,>=,<=. I wrote some code, yet it still show some errors(8 errors on 97 tests) in my course tester. I don't have details about tests. Can someone tell me where errors can come from?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool rowne(string a, string b)
{
    if (a.length() == b.length())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i)
        {
            if (a[i] != b[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    else if (a.size() != b.size())
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool mniejsze(string a, string b)
{

    if ((a.length() < b.length()))
    {
        return true;
    } 

    else if (a.length() == b.length())
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < a.length(); ++z)
        {
            if (a[z] - '0' < b[z] - '0')
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    else if (a.length() > b.length())
        return false;
}

int main()
{
    string znak;
    string a;
    string b;
    bool p = false;
    cin >> a >> znak >> b;

    while (a[0] == '0' && a.length() != 1)
    {
        a.erase(0, 1);

    }
    while (b[0] == '0' && b.length() != 1)
    {
        b.erase(0, 1);

    }
    if (znak == "==")
    {
        if (rowne(a, b) == true)
            p = true;
    } 
    else if (znak == "!=")
    {
        if (rowne(a, b) != true)
            p = true;
    }
    else if (znak == "<")
    {
        if (mniejsze(a, b))
            p = true;
    } 
    else if (znak == ">")
    {
        if (mniejsze(b, a))
            p = true;
    } 
    else if (znak == "<=")
    {
        if (mniejsze(b, a) != true)
            p = true;
    } 
    else if (znak == ">=")
    {
        if (mniejsze(a, b) == false)
            p = true;
    }

    if (p == true)
        cout << "YES";
    else if (p == false)
        cout << "NO";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since this is coursework, its very valuable for you to figure this out on your own, but here's a generic helpful tip for that. Since your course tester does not ell you what cases failed and which succeeded, you should make your own cases to find ones that fail. If you still don't find any problems, try to list all assumptions you are making and reexamine them.

Comment: Is your code meant to work only for positive numbers? Otherwise, `-1<1` gives `NO`.

Comment: The task says numbers from 1<a,b<10^1000, so i don't think there are negative numbers. Also there is a problem, because the course has a limit to sending files and i am close to this limit, so sending parts and examining can't be done.

Comment: Each non-English identifier reduces your audience by a factor of 3.62.

Comment: negative and/or explicitly positive numbers (with a leading '+' character) are not handled. Can there be leading/trailing spaces? If so - you've got trim those as well before comparing numbers. You also don't **make sure** those are digits, i.e. your code will *happily* compare this input without complaining: "XIX == nineteen"

Comment: A potentially useful observation: `if (a[z] - '0' < b[z] - '0')` is the same as `if (a[z] < b[z])`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine for the "happy path" execution, i.e. when both inputs are well-formed and the comparison operator (the `znak`?) is one of the pre-defined ones. However one can (and you **must**) come up with a set of negative tests designed to "break" your code. Here's a short list of things that come to mind for testing:

1. leading/trailing spaces
2. leading +/- sign
3. non-digit characters (roman numbers, e.g. XIX or CVIII; spelled-out numbers, e.g. "five", other non-number-related characters, e.g. "$", "@", etc)
4. use of an invalid comparison operator, e.g. an input like "123 equals 123"
5. what happens when you are asked to compare two *empty* strings?

One of the bugs a non-digit character would expose in your code is that this line:

```
if (a[z] - '0' < b[z] - '0')
```

will totally break for ASCII characters below `'0'`, like `'$'` (because that would produce negative numbers, or produce an integer overflow, after subtracting the `'0'` - all depends on whether a `char` is defined as signed or unsigned for your build)